# how to prevent xss attacks and sql injection in magento 2

Tags: magento2, security

I need to know if there are some configuration from Bo or some patch to prevent those type of attack.

Answer (score 3):

**Prevent xss attacks and sql injection in magento 2**

You have to implement below steps:

- Upgrade your Magento version to latest version
- Enabled /use Magento google Captcha extension.
- Audit your application files/folder permission and ownership.
- Audit 3rd party extension, if this extension has any security lick.
- One of most import integrates **Web firewall** like Sucuri and
  Cloudflare. Web firewall protected block bad and boot request.

Comment: i use the 2.2.6 and what's the meaning of the last phrase is there something do i have to add as extension or what and really thanks for your replay